# Is it possible to use dynamic gulp.dest directories?

Tags: gulp

We're using Gulp for a setup where we want to compile our CSS to a specific `dist/assets/css` folder which works totally fine using `.pipe(gulp.dest('./frontend/dist/assets/css'))`.

In the same project we'll have another folder where our back-end resides and we want to output our CSS to that location as well. The problem is, the directory names of the projects differ everytime. For example, in one project it could be `./src/Project.Web/assets/css` while in another project the destination would be `./src/MyAwesomeProject.Web/assets/css`. Note that the destination path is *always* affixed with `.Web`.

So, is it possible to output to a dynamic folder using `gulp.dest`? And if so, how could this be achieved?

Comment: just use * ?      ...

Comment: @YOU: how would you implement that?

Comment: src/*.Web/assets/css?

Comment: Already tried that, it'll create a folder '*.Web'...

Answer (score -1):

Gulp Inject allows for that type of setup: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject